# Why it didn't get current EditText value

Tags: android

I'm doing basic demo of android related to login, update user

I used user's id from login page to load user's information to update page

```
 username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtUsername);
 age = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtAge);
 weight  = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtWeight);
 height = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtHeight);
 username.setText(db_username);
 age.setText(db_age);
 weight.setText(db_weight);
 height.setText(db_height);
```

and update button

```
update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        int sweight = Integer.parseInt(weight.getText().toString());
        double sheight = Double.parseDouble(height.getText().toString());
        int sage = Integer.parseInt(age.getText().toString());
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (weight.equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please input weight!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }else if(height.equals("")){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please input height!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }else if(age.equals("")){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please input age!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }else{
                dbHandler.updateUser(sid,sweight,sheight,sage);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "User's information updated! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        sid+sweight+sheight+sage+" and test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                Intent i = new Intent(UserUpdate.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();

            }
        }
    });
```

For exam: weight: 70,height:1,65,age:21
when i changed it to: weight:50,height:1,65,age:21
the 2nd Toast show me that weight : 70 but not 50

Comment: You probably should also use `setError` on the EditTexts instead of Toasting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move these top three lines inside of the click method, not declare them as member variables of the anonymous class.

```
    int sweight = Integer.parseInt(weight.getText().toString());
    double sheight = Double.parseDouble(height.getText().toString());
    int sage = Integer.parseInt(age.getText().toString());

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // Move them here
```

Answer (score 0):

put this :

```
    int sweight = Integer.parseInt(weight.getText().toString());
    double sheight = Double.parseDouble(height.getText().toString());
    int sage = Integer.parseInt(age.getText().toString());
```

in onclick method  , before  ->  if (weight.equals(""))